# What does "play me close" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From Maroon 5's “Girls Like You”:

> Roll that Backwood, babe, and **play me close.**

Slang websites show the phrase means “trick” or “deceive” but I'm not sure this is what the singer means.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, trying to interpret contemporary pop song lyrics must involve a certain amount of guesswork, but the line could mean "make a joint from a cigar and then watch me closely". A 'Backwood' is a US brand of cigar, popular among smokers of marijuana in that language zone for use as the basis for rolling a 'blunt' (a hollowed-out cigar filled with marijuana). Some slang websites offer another meaning of 'play me close', that is, "watch me attentively".

[Playing me close](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=playing%20me%20close)

Answer (score 2):

I was at first doubtful about how "Play Me Close" was interpreted but other lyrics like:

> Maybe it's 6:45
> Maybe I'm barely alive
> Maybe you've taken my shit for the last time, yeah
> Maybe I know that I'm drunk
> Maybe I know you're the one
> Maybe you thinking it's better if you drive

They tell me Michael Harvey's interpretation of "Play me Close" is spot on as the explanation of Roll that Backwood, babe